# RowUpdating GridView Showing Old value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Row editing and Row canceling editing working fine; but when I press update after changing the value in textbox, it show the old value not that value that I have change.The following is Row updating event code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

dao.AridNumber = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
dao.FirstName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
dao.LastName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;

}
```

update me!

Comment: I would also check the Needs Binding I can't remember what event that is but sounds like a DataBind() issue

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to bind the data again at the last of the method inorder to show you the appropriate result.

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 2):

Check your markup that you're using Bind() as opposed to Eva() to bind the value to the TextBox.

Here is an example:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="someId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SomeField") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have recently came across the same problem you have faced , when i tried to update the value in grid. I have called the Gridbind in Pageload that's the cause of the issue.
Are you using any function to bind the gridview or something like that?

and if you are using that function in page_load event then you wont get the updated value cause on postback it rebinds ur gridview and you will lose ur updated value.

Comment: Thanks to the above comment I put `if (!IsPostBack) {}` around the Gridview.Databind(); section in Page_Load and it fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call GridView1.DataBind() in the end:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

      dao.AridNumber = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
      dao.FirstName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
      dao.LastName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;

      GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Edit:**

You might want to check out the [RowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) documentation, especially I think that [OldValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx) and [NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) properties might be of use to you.

Comment: after using GridView1.DataBind(); no change in the result! actually dear, when I debug the project, the value comes from grid are old. not new. because I want to insert new value in database that I have entered before pressing update

Comment: My problem is, when I enter new value after pressing edit button, as I press update, it show me new value at property dao.AridNumber, but it showing old value, because after new value I will update the database

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor - I'm not really sure that I understand completely what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to save your old values and then continue with the updating of the GridView with the new values?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor - Check out the links in the edit. Is this of any help to you?

Comment: Actually I do not keep the old value. with reference to the image on the top that I have shared, as I press edit, it enable the complete row to modify the contents, and also shows two buttons update and cancel as second row in the above image. after entering new values in second row, I want new value as I press update button.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor I think that the NewValues property can help you with that. See the link in the answer. There's also an example there.